# Type error in js

Tags: javascript

I typed the following code

```
var curdte=new Date();  
var curdteyr=curdte.getYear();  
var curdtemh=curdte.getMonth();     
var curdtedy=curdte.getDay();   
var dtecurr=(curdtedy "-" curdtemh "-" curdteyr);     
var fyear1=fromdat1.substring(6,10,10);     
var fmonth1=fromdat1.substring(3,5,10);     
var fday1=fromdat1.substring(0,2,10);   
var fmdiff=(fday1 "-" fmonth1 "-" fyear1);      
var frmdate1=(fyear1 "-" fmonth1 "-" fday1);    
var tyear1=todat1.substring(6,10,10);   
var tmonth1=todat1.substring(3,5,10);   
var tday1=todat1.substring(0,2,10);     
var todiff=(tday1 "-" tmonth1 "-" tyear1);      
var todate3=(tyear1 "-" tmonth1 "-" tday1);     
var oneday=24*60*60*1000;   
var frmdiff=new Date(Math.ceil(dtecurr.getTime()-fmdiff.getTime())/oneday);
```

Then I get the error :

> TypeError: dtecurr.getTime is not a function

Comment: I am wondering why don't you get `SyntaxError: Unexpected string`....

Answer (score 3):

That is because dtecurr is not a Date object, it *should* be a formatted string but is missing the `+` for concatenation. I've passed dtecurr to Date.parse, which should create a valid Date object to call `getTime` on:

```
var frmdiff=new Date(Math.ceil(Date.parse(dtecurr).getTime()-fmdiff.getTime())/oneday);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dtecurr` is a string.  Just because it is formatted like a user-friendly date, doesn't mean it's an instance of `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
var dtecurr=new Date(curdtedy + "-" + curdtemh + "-" + curdteyr);
```

instead of

```
var dtecurr=(curdtedy "-" curdtemh "-" curdteyr);
```

Comment: Even with correct string concatenation, `getTime` will still be a string and not a `Date` object

Comment: @Rob M.:Right, fixed :).

Comment: I'm wondering how the code got far enough to give him that error :P

Comment: Yep, just 15 secs back I commented similarly on the question itself :D

Answer (score 0):

That is because dtecurr is not a Date object here.

Make it a Date object:

```
var dtecurr = new Date();
```

And then set values by methods `setDate()`, `setMonth()` and `setFullYear()`